# ASP.NET Thread Execution

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have an ASP.NET application which allow users to upload files which will later be moved to AWS S3. Everything works alright if the file is uploaded and moved to S3 on a single request. But the problem is the user has to wait while uploading the file and also while moving it to S3. So what I did is, I first save the file in the server after upload is complete, and spawn a new thread which will move the file to S3, so that the user doesn't have to wait for that part. Since I am on a shared hosting environment, I think, the thread is getting aborted with no traces of any errors. From various web pages I could figure out that this could be due to AppPool recycling done by the IIS.

Is there any way to prevent this until the thread execution is completed?

Comment: Are you handling AppDomain.UnhandledException or have a top-level exception handler in your spawned thread?

Comment: In the thread I have a simple Try-Catch block that handles any errors while uploading to S3. I do not handle AppDomain.UnhandledException.